# Get forward kinematics (w/o tf service call) from URDF & joint angles (Kinetic, Python)

Tags: ros, python, forward-kinematics, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Context:
I am writing a python ROS node that:

1. Parses a URDF (from param server) and generates a [trac_ik_python](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_python/) IK object.
2. Generates an end-effector trajectory between the current location (xyz) and a target location (xyz).
3. Then for each pt in the end-effector trajectory [(x0,y0,z0),(x1,y1,z1),...,(xn,yn,zn)].
4. Gets joint angles from [HEBI-X5](http://hebirobotics.com/) actuator.
5. Calculates joint angles using trac_ik_python.
6. Publishes joint angles to HEBI-X5.

---

Problem:
Inside the trajectory execution loop, I would like to know the actual end-effector position (based on some KDL tree and the HEBI actuator joint angle sensors).

If possible, I'd like to create the KDL object from the urdf - and just update it with the new joint angles.

---

Possible Solution:
This [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/250127/best-way-to-get-fk-for-many-different-joint-states/?answer=250146#post-id-250146) recommends using [urdf_parser_py.urdf and pykdl_utils.kdl_kinematics](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils#kdl_kinematics.KDLKinematics)
... unfortunately, [pykdl_utils](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils#kdl_kinematics.KDLKinematics) does not appear to be in ROS Kinetic.

---

Questions:

- What's the best way to obtain forward kinematics from a urdf and joint angles (w/o using a tf service call - too slow)?
- Is there a Kinetic substitute for pykdl_utils?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281272/get-forward-kinematics-(w/o-tf-service-call)-from-urdf-&-joint-angles-(kinetic,-python)/) by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easy workaround is to simply copy the hrl-kdl repository into your workspace: https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/hrl-kdl
So far, the forward kinematics (from urdf and sensor joint angles) have been correct - which is all that I want right now.

```
from urdf_parser_py.urdf import URDF
from pykdl_utils.kdl_kinematics import KDLKinematics

# pykdl_utils setup
robot_urdf = URDF.from_xml_string(urdf_str)
kdl_kin = KDLKinematics(robot_urdf, base_link, end_link)

test_jt_angles = [0, 0, 0]
pose = kdl_kin.forward(test_jt_angles)
```

---

Alternatively, you could re-implement pykdl_utils using http://wiki.ros.org/urdfdom_py and  http://wiki.ros.org/python_orocos_kdl

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked a [similar question](https://answers.ros.org/question/280643/python-forward-kinematics/) a couple of days ago that went unanswered. I've since decided to dig into the source for the package [python_orocos_kdl](http://wiki.ros.org/python_orocos_kdl) that I think will address both of our needs (though the documentation is definitely lacking). I'll update my question/the docs once I'm able to get something working.

---

Originally posted by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) with karma: 156 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-01-31**:
Hmm, thanks for pointer - right now looking at using [kdl_parser_py](https://github.com/ros/kdl_parser/blob/kinetic-devel/kdl_parser_py/kdl_parser_py/urdf.py) and [python_orocos_kdl](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/python_orocos_kdl/tests/kinfamtest.py).

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-01-31**:
^ The two python modules I linked (kdl_parser_py.urdf and python_orocos_kdl.kinfamtest) seem to provide the most promising implementation. You are correct. Neither package has a well-documented Python interface.